# using $P$ in place of $P^T$ when doing graph isomorphism through matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory

Let $G,H$ be simple graphs, and $A_G,A_H$ their adjacency matrices. Let $P$ be a permutation matrix, representing the permutation $\pi$.

I'm currently trying to understand why two graphs are isomorphic iff $PA_GP^T = A_H$ (I know that $P^{-1} = P^T$). In particular, I want to prove that $G,H$ are isomorphic iff there exists $P$ permutation matrix such that $PA_G = A_HP$. For the $PA_G = A_HP$, I can see that it goes back to proving $PA_GP^{-1} = A_H$. The thing is, I can't understand (nor explain) why to use $P^T$?

What I've seen is that if I do $PA_G$, I apply $\pi$ to the rows of $A_G$. Conversely, if I do $A_GP$, I apply $\pi$ to the columns of $A_G$.

My question is: why is the condition $PA_GP^T = A_H$ instead of $PA_GP = A_H$? What is the difference between using $P$ and $P^T$? If multiplying by $P$ on the right still shuffles the columns, why don't we use it? $P^T$ surely represents $\pi^{-1}$, right?

Comment: Do you know about conjugations from group theory?

Comment: @CharlesHudgins yes, I know a little about it. Looking at it that way, $A_H$ would be the conjugate of $A_G$ by $P$. I'm sorry, but I can't see any further than that. What does this fact imply?

Comment: Conjugations are, very generally, how one changes "coordinates." The first P changes your "coordinates" to a different way of labeling the vertices of the graph, the $A_G$ says how those coordinates are connected in that labeling, and then the $P^{-1}$ changes things back to labels the $A_H$ can "understand."